# Python Regex using a wildcard to match the beginning of a string and replacing the entire string

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm trying to match the beginning of a word and then replace the entire word with something.  Below is what I'm trying to do.

```
add23khh234 > REMOVED
add2asdf675 > REMOVED
```

Below is the regex statement I'm using.

```
string_reg = re.sub(ur'add*', 'REMOVED', string_reg)
```

But this code gives me the following.

```
add23khh234 > REMOVED23khh234
add2asdf675 > REMOVED2asdf675
```

Answer (score 1):

`add*` is `ad '*d'`. [From the document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `'*'`
>
> Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. `ab*` will match `a`, `ab`, or `a` followed by any number of `b`s.

So it matchs `ad` or `add` or `adddddd...`. But it doesn't match neither `add23khh234` nor `add2asdf675`(or something like these).

You should use `.+?` or `.*?` here(not `.*`, that's greedy). Try something like this:

```
string_reg = re.sub(ur'add.+? ', 'REMOVED ', string_reg)
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> string_reg = """\
... add23khh234 > REMOVED23khh234
... add2asdf675 > REMOVED2asdf675"""

>>> string_reg = re.sub(ur'add.+? ', 'REMOVED ', string_reg)
>>> print string_reg
REMOVED > REMOVED23khh234
REMOVED > REMOVED2asdf675
>>>
```

Comment: This is correct, except that `.+*` doesn't make sense. I think you meant `.*?`.

Comment: @EdCottrell Oops, I always use `.+?` :P. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string_reg = re.sub(ur'^add.*', 'REMOVED', string_reg)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have mulitple patterns on one line

```
string_reg=re.sub("add[^ ]+","REMOVED",string_reg)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

```
\badd\w*
```

---

A [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) such as `*` is applied to the previous token or subpattern. for example, the regex you're using `add*` matches a literal `ad` followed by any number of subsequent `d`.

**Meeting your criteria**

- You need to match `add` at the **beggining** of a word, so use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
- Then you also need to match the rest of the word in order to replace it. `\w` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which matches 1 word character, and that's what you need to repeat any number of times with `*`.

**Code**

```
import re

string_reg = 'add23khh234 ... add2asdf675 ... xxxadd2axxx'

string_reg = re.sub(ur'\badd\w*', 'REMOVED', string_reg)
print(string_reg)
```

**Output**

```
REMOVED ... REMOVED ... xxxadd2axxx
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/OITwzE)</kbd>